# How can I fix this error : non supported SQL92?

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, jdbc

I wirte code in java and database connection with oracle. I run some script and get this error.My script work in toad but not work in my project

url include 
.

```
.
.
.
.
    DECODE
                 (REF.target_type_code,
                  '1', wf.workflow_name,
                  '20', reqtyp.request_type_name,
                  '6', prj1.project_name,
                  '59', trootinfo1.NAME,
                  '55', DECODE
                     (document.checked_out_by,
                      NULL, 
                      REPLACE
                         (REPLACE
                             (REPLACE
                                 (REPLACE
                                     (REPLACE
                                         (knta_i18n_resource.get
                                             ('DMS_REFERENCE_DETAIL_CHECKED_OUT.TXT'
                                             ),
                                          knta_i18n_format_utils.format_date
                                                        (document.checked_in_date,
                                                         3 
                                                        )
                                         )
                                     ),
                                  document.version_number
                                 ) 
                             ),
                          '{4}' 
                         )
                     )
                 ) reference_detail,

.
.
.
```

.

```
try { 
    stmt = connection.createStatement(); 
    rset =   stmt.executeQuery(url) ;  
}  catch (Exception e) 

{  
    error= e.getLocalizedMessage() ;
    return 4; 
}
```

this error occurs because of { } parentheses. I test it .
When I delete parentheses dont error. But I need them and How can I fix this?

Comment: Show your query. Your query seems to be incorrect.

Comment: my query works in toad but not run in my netbeans

Comment: If you want to get help, consider two things. 1) `url include " {2} "`: it is not enough to post this as an error message. Post whole error message. 2) you should also post the value of the `url` variable before you call `stmt.executeQuery(url)`.

Comment: @Ersin, nobody will be able to help based on the fact it works in TOAD. Post the statement string.

Comment: Replace `{}` this with `()` and try it out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's all about `{` and  `}`. You do not use them. Ojdbc won't parse it. Use different token instead of them.

Comment: which token should I use? I just met the same problem when I call a procedure with jdbc

Comment: you can use anything you want. F.E. use _xx_  , replace it first and then re-replace it to reverse

Comment: what does it mean, I am facing the same challenge, if I replace it with (), it is not working too. i am in bad situation, can anyone please help which token should i use here instead of {}.

Comment: what is your code ? are tou sure not using { and }

Answer (score 3):

This is probably due to the JDBC Escape syntax (see section 13.4 of the JDBC 4.1 specification). A JDBC driver should handle escapes between `{` and `}` and translate the escaped standard function, outer join etc to the database specific format.

As far as I know a driver should only parse the escapes if it occurs in the statement body itself, and not when it is inside text in the statement (as it is in your example). So to me this looks like a bug in the JDBC escape processing of your driver.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get around this by following the answer of another StackOverflow post:
[Create Java on Oracle database with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141737/create-java-on-oracle-database-with-jdbc)

A summary is:

```
CallableStatement stat = conn.prepareCall(sql);
stat.setEscapeProcessing(false);
stat.execute();
```

The middle line is what you seem to be missing. I couldn't figure it out until I found that post.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that several of the REPLACE calls do not have enough arguments.  Counting from the left, the first REPLACE has two arguments.  The second only has one argument.  The third has two arguments.  The fourth only has one argument.  The fifth (last) has two arguments.  In Oracle the [REPLACE function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions141.htm#i78608) requires at least two arguments.  I'm not able to determine if this is the cause of the error as you haven't posted a complete statement, but I'd certainly expect the lack of proper arguments to REPLACE to be a problem.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'{4}'` with `CHR(123)||'4'||CHR(125)` in your script.