# Callablestatement error : Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to run Oracle's **CREATE JAVA** statement.

We have had to set CallableStatement.setEscapeProcessing to false to avoid troubles with question marks. This works fine for most of our statements, but in the case of a Java switch statement, we are getting the exception below :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

I suppose it has something to do with the colons used in the switch statement.

Here's an example of the problem :

**JDBCTest.java**

```
package jdbctest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class JDBCTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String data = readScript("/tmp/Demo.sql");        

        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement callStat = null;
        try {
            String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@193.53.40.220:1521:ora11";
            String username = "";
            String password = "";

            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            callStat = conn.prepareCall(data);
            callStat.setEscapeProcessing(false);
            callStat.execute();
        } finally {
            try {callStat.close();} catch (Exception ex){}
            try {conn.close();} catch (Exception ex){}
        }

    }

    private static String readScript(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            String currentLine;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(filename), "ISO-8859-1"));

            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                currentLine = currentLine.replaceAll("^\\s+$", "");
                currentLine = currentLine.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
                stringBuilder.append(currentLine).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            try { reader.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}            
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

**Demo.sql**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "jdbctest" AS

package jdbctest;

public class Demo {
    public void test()
    {
        int a = 3;
        switch (a)
        {
            case 1: System.out.println("1"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("2"); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("3"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

This was run using ojdbc6.jar (as the JDBC driver) on a 11gR2 Oracle database.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the colon? Also the last character `/` is not a PLSQL command but an SQL*Plus command and won't likely work in java.

Comment: My bad. We usually do all kinds of formatting to the PL/SQL code before running it against the database. The ending `/` would normally have been removed. I edited my question to remove the `/`. When removing the colons, the code runs fine.

Comment: Does it work if you use a regular `Statement` instead of a `CallableStatement`?

Comment: It does! `statement = conn.createStatement(); statement.setEscapeProcessing(false); statement.execute(data);` did the trick! Please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you use a [`Statement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) instead of a [`CallableStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

You should use `Statement` for all DDL, `PreparedStatement` for DML and `CallableStatement` for procedure calls. Creating a procedure is DDL.

A `CallableStatement` will try to detect and bind variables identified by a colon `:` so this is probably why your code didn't work.

Comment: Note that without Statement.setEscapeProcessing(false) I had following error : `Non supported SQL92 token at position [...]` . Thanks Vincent!

Comment: Do you also need `setEscapeProcessing(false)` with a `Statement`?

Comment: Yes,in my case it would complain about `Non supported SQL92 token at position [...]` if I didn't.