# JDBC CallableStatement - call multiple stored procedures in one shot

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, java-stored-procedures

To call Oracle's stored procedure using only simple JDBC in Java we could do something like this:

```
con.prepareCall("{ call ? = my_procedure(?) }");
callStm.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
callStm.setInt(2, -100);
callStm.execute()
```

I want to know is it somehow possible to call more then one procedure inside one `prepareCall` statement? For example:

```
con.prepareCall("{ call prepare_proc(); ? = my_procedure(?) }");
```

Of course it is not valid, but how to fix it and call two or more procedures in one shot?

Comment: You should wrap those in another procedure, or you can even write a `PL/SQL` instead of using the call syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap them in an anonymous block:

```
con.prepareCall("begin prepare_proc(); ? := my_procedure(?); end;");
```

[Read more about the differences.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jajdb/index.html?oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html)

The assignment of the the function's return value to the bind variable (the first `?`) is now [a PL/SQL assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-B91BEA99-974B-4CE7-8B28-A5B78A6918F7), within the anonymous block, so it uses `? := ...`. In your original code you were using the [`call` SQL statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CALL.html) version (`? = call ...`), and JDBC uses a plain `=` for the assignment to the bind variable.

Presumably `my_procedure` is actually `my_function`, otherwise it won't have a return type...

It would probably be more maintainable to have a wrapper procedure (or function) which makes both calls, and then just call that single wrapper over JDBC.

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for the given example. It works. To others: Please noticed the different between `call ? = my_function` and `begin ? := my_function` - there is colon `:` before equal sign. Maybe it's obvious but I want to point this.

Comment: And another hint: In my situation I obtain an error `non supported SQL92` after execution of given example. It is because JDBC driver sometimes has problem with parsing/escaping some characters. So the `{` and `}` can be removed, because there are `begin` and `end` statements and then everything work just fine. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281574 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16237096 (because you may disable Escape Processing in JDBC if you want).

Comment: @jsosnowski - good points - leaving the curly braces in was an oversight; and I meant to (but then forgot) to highlight the assignment needing `:=`. I've updated and added a bit about the difference int he assignment.

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer is great. And I was looking for the documentation which you provide in first link - thanks. I wish I could give you more than one upvote.