# Oracle sql script syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I try to run this sql script in Oracle 11g r2 it gives below error;

> Non supported SQL92 token

Is there any idea what is the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE additional_doc_ref 
(uuid VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
 id VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL, 
 date ${date.type} NOT NULL, 
 code VARCHAR2(200), 
 draft VARCHAR2(50), 
 data BLOB, 
 document_type_code VARCHAR2(100), 
 document_type VARCHAR2(200), 
 external_reference VARCHAR2(200), 
 embedded_binary_obj BLOB, 

 CONSTRAINT PK_ADDITIONAL_DOC_REF PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it s all about '{' and '}'. You do not use them. ojdbc dont parse it. use different token instead of them.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244591/how-can-i-fix-this-error-non-supported-sql92)