# How to load large .sql script against oracle database using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have a sql script for oracle database:

```
set define off;
   CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "XYZ" AS
   import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
.......
   import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
public class XYZ {
   .... fields
   .... methods
}
/
```

I'm trying to execute this statement using following java code:

```
String createStoredProcedureSqlString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(storedProcedureSqlFile.toPath()));
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
     Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
    statement.execute(createStoredProcedureSqlString);
    }
```

After executing this code I faced with exception message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 479
```

I believe that this exception occurs while script contains "{" or "}" symbols. But I don't really know how to escape them and not affect script itself.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244591/how-can-i-fix-this-error-non-supported-sql92?

Comment: Yes, I did. This topic is all about replacing { symbol. This solution doesn't suit me

Comment: I believe this would be your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12281574/3179169. You cannot use { } and the comments say that you can use some other characters and then replace it.

Comment: Why the need to run through JDBC?  Just use sqlplus.

Comment: I doubt JDBC is going to understand SQL*Plus commands like `set define off;` Surely it expects a single SQL statement.

Comment: @clinomaniac, When I replace {} with any other symbol I get: 
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29536: badly formed source: