# How to fix "Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 48" Jmeter testing

Tags: java, jmeter

in the given jdbc request i have the query as "select fo_ide from order_info where order_id=${OrderIDA}" and variable name as OrderIDA.

after some checking around its the issues with using "{" and "}" what else can I use instead? as I need parameter to be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix this error : non supported SQL92?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244591/how-can-i-fix-this-error-non-supported-sql92)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `OrderIDA` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is not defined hence JMeter is sending it as `${OrderIDA}` instead of the respective value.

You can double check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)

Re-visit the place where you declare the variable and amend JMeter configuration accordingly.